# Combined Torah/College programs for women in the NYC area

Tags: product-recommendation, yeshiva-school, college-university-school

What learning programs are available for women in the New York City metro area that provide a curriculum in both Jewish studies and a bachelors and/or associates degree in secular topics? I'm thinking of a program specifically with an Orthodox Jewish approach, not something that has a Judaic Studies department.

In any answers, I would appreciate an overview of what the Torah part of the curriculum covers and what type of student background it expects.

Comment: Stern College at YU?

Comment: Do you mean like at [Touro College](https://www.touro.edu/fields/jewish-studies/) such as the course of study shown at [Landers](https://las.touro.edu/women/programs-and-majors/majors/judaic-studies.php)

Comment: YU and Touro are the schools that have dual curriculums. There are several seminary programs (like there are many Yeshiva programs) that partner with colleges to give people the opportunity to get a degree in an established college while remaining in their current religious institution.

Comment: There are a lot of these in Brooklyn. Are you looking for Chabad?

Comment: @sah any and all orthodox denominations